# What does Chandler mean by "turtles came up"?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

In *Friends* Season 3 Episode 25 the following scene happens:

> [Scene: The beach house, the next morning. Chandler and Monica are in
>   the kitchen eating breakfast.]
>
> Rachel: (entering) Well! Is everybody else having just the best time?!
>   Well, I assume the happy couple isn’t up yet. Did you guys hear them
>   last night?
>
> Chandler: Oh, yeah, I don’t know what they were doing, but at one
>   point sea turtles actually came up to the house.

I am not sure what Chandler is referring to here, but I have three interpretations:

1. That the turtles was angry from the sex noises and they came to demand silence.
2. That the sounds they were making sounded like a summoning technique for those turtles.
3. That I am wrong, and it is something totally different.

Answer (score 16):

Pretty sure it's **number 2.** While not very scientifically sound (sea turtles can't hear very well, if at all), the sounds a tortoise makes while mating are quite loud and a bit human-like [***Warning: Turtle Love***]:

Comment: Upvoting just for the warning...

Comment: A less graphic interpretation https://i.ytimg.com/vi/axZ6mG__ZqU/maxresdefault.jpg they were just rooting for them